# Create a collapsible divs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a collapsible divs (arranged in a column) which takes always the same height when open.
For example, if one div is open, it takes 100% of the height. If two are open, each takes 50% etc.
I set flex-grow: 1 on each div, but the one with bigger content is always higher then others. I tried also to set
fles-basis: 0, but then they do not open at all.

Here is the link to my minimal example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-meadow-hyr31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Collapsible.module.css add height=100vh to open style:

```
.open {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: I see that the solution works, but could you tell something more about how it works? Why a div with height equal to 100vh takes 50% height in case of 2 elements, 33% in case of 3 and so on, and not actually 100vh as we set?

Comment: I included an example, I hope that helps. I attended a google conference and there is much more to this, but to summarize, it's better to use vh for heights and stick with percent for widths because percentage can behave weird for heights and similarly vw, can be unpredictable in some rare occasions.

Answer (score 1):

To explain why the solution above works, one vh is equal to 1% of the viewport, the browser will always compute the values in pixels, to see a simple example :

```js
one = document.querySelector('.one');
two = document.querySelector('.two');
one.innerText = one.clientHeight;
two.innerText = two.clientHeight;
```

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
div {
    height: 100vh;
}
.one {
    background-color: chocolate;
}
.two {
    background-color: cyan;
}
.three {
    background-color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">one</div>
<div class="two">two</div>
```

If you add a third div with a class 'three' the browser will assign each the third of the available height of the viewport. 100vh is not an absolute measure, the only absolute values are the one you put in pixels (although even that can change sometimes if your elements are not considered responsive enough by the browser).